# Ruby Instance Variable Syntax

Tags: ruby

I'm finishing The Well Grounded Rubyist and I've noticed some instance variable calls that I don't quite understand.  Straight from TWGR (Section 15.2.2):

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name
  def name=(name)
    @name = name
    normalize_name
  end

  private
  def normalize_name
    name.gsub!(/[^-a-z'.\s]/i, "")
  end
end
```

Is the `name` variable in the normalize_name method an implicit instance variable?  Would `@name.gsub!(/[^-a-z'.\s]/i, "")` have worked just as well?  Is there some convention I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening in `normalize_name` is that `name` resolves to the method `self.name`, which is defined by the `attr_reader` class macro at the top of the class. If you were to use `attr_accessor` instead, the `name=` method would be defined as well (but it wouldn't include the call to `normalize_name`.

These getter and setter methods automatically access instance variables. The `name` method defined by `attr_accessible :name` looks like this, essentially:

```
def name
  @name
end
```

Comment: Would referencing the `@name` variable directly instead of the `name` method have worked?  Is there an advantage to using the `name` method?

Comment: Yup. They do the same basic thing, but it's safer to use the getter — what if later down the line you decide to modify the data on read instead of on write?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the `name` variable in the normalize_name method an implicit instance variable?

No, it's not an instance variable. Instance variables start with an `@` sigil, this doesn't, ergo, it cannot possibly be an instance variable. In fact, it's not a variable *at all*, it's a message send.